# Multiple dynamic query scope

Tags: php, laravel

I have build a filter on my database query and now 
I want to make it more comfortable. 
The goal is to make it dynamic that mean's
the user has the option to combine as many as he wants.

```
public function filter(FilterList $request)
{
    $view = view('profile.browse.list');
    $search = $request->get('filter');

    $filter = [
            'male'   => Profile::male(),
            'female' => Profile::female(),
            '10'     => Profile::man(),
            '11'     => Profile::women(),
            '12'     => Profile::couple(),
            '15'     => Profile::domina(),
            '20'     => Profile::affaire(),
            '21'     => Profile::cybersex(),
            '22'     => Profile::marriage(),
            '23'     => Profile::flirt(),
    ];

    return $view->with([
        'List' => $filter[$search]->unmoderated()->paginate(15)->appends(['filter' => $search]),
    ]);

}
```

I know that my solution is not really a good solution.
I have saved the query scopes in the $filter array and
can not add a a second or thired scope like this

`$users = User::popular()->women()->orderBy('created_at')->get();`

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes

Have anyony hint's for me for making it better.

I have no idea to start ...

Thanks for any help

**Edit**

```
public function scopeMarriage($query)
{
 return $query->where('LookFor', 'LIKE', '%Ehe%');
}
```

Comment: You'll need to create a class which registers filters and applies them to the  `user` query builder. Maybe i'll get on it, when i've some time on my hands.

Comment: How is a scope look like? Could you add one to your question?

Comment: Meanwhile, I have an Idea to solve my problem.
It is possible to create a methode call in a loop ?
Maybe like this ... 

http://pastie.org/10513248

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the user is submitting a dynamic number of inputs, and based on those inputs, you want to keep chaining query scopes onto your query? If that's what you want, I believe you can do something like this this:

```
// Method array taken from your example
$methods = [
    'male'    => 'male',
    'female'  => 'female',
    '12'      => 'couple',
];

// Begin the query. Since the unmoderated() scope query is always called,
// I used that in this example.
// But note that you can also use Model::query(); to begin a query
$query = Profile::unmoderated();

// Loop through the request inputs
foreach ($request->all() as $param)
{
    // If it exists in the provided array, add it to the query.
    if (array_key_exists($param, $methods))
    {
        $query->{$methods[$param]}();
    }
}

// Call get, paginate, etc. to actually fetch the results and then return it.
return $query->paginate(15);
```

Comment: > But note that you can also use Model::query(); to begin a query

This line helped me. Thank you so much.